# Can't ctrl drag Views to header file

Tags: ios

Hi I'm very new to ios development.

I'm developing a map application where I use mapkit. I have a viewController with the map view and a corresponding viewController class.

Now I would like to manipulate the mapView, and is trying to set up the delegate. BUT i can't ctrl+drag anything (includes the mapView) to my header-file. So what do I do then??

I've tried to write the auto implemented stuff in my header-file but this isn't working either :(

Any help is really appreciated..

Here's my header-file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

#define METERS_PER_MILE 1609.344

@interface MapViewController : UIViewController<MKMapViewDelegate> {

}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

@end
```

And a note to ios developers what the hell is this drag and drop doing in a IDE?!?

Comment: Which XCode version? Also to answer your second question (what the hell is this drag and drop doing in a IDE): Makes your life simpler by generating stubs and setting outlets to nil upon deallocation (if needed) :)

Comment: I'm using xcode 4.2. Is there some documentations on the drag and drop issue, what's happens behind the scenes and such, tried to search a bit around without luck :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are the steps to create an IBOutlet in XCode:

1. Click on your `xib` / `Storyboard` to edit it in Interface Builder
2. Bring the view for which you want to create an outlet in front
3. Make sure that `Assistant editor` is visible. If not click on this icon:
   [image]
4. Now you should see your source file next to your UI editor (also make sure that you've set the custom class of your controller in the identity inspector)
5. **Important**: Make sure that your editor is **not** zoomed out. Click on the **=** button to do so.
6. Set the assistant mode to '**Automatic**' if you don't see your header file and control+drag to your source to create the `IBOutlet`
   [image]

I hope that this will clarify the whole procedure for you. Note that this is only a convenience. You could manually declare the `IBOutlet` and connect it to your view as well.

Comment: Thanks for the explicit answare! My problem was I hadn't sat the ViewController class in the Identity Inspector, after this the "Automatic" worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the assistant type is set to counterparts [image]
sometimes xcode will automatically set this to manual and you will be trying to drag to a header that had nothing to do with your xib