# Can't create a new IBOutlet connection; Ctrl+dragging doesn't work

Tags: ios, xcode, iboutletcollection

This solution "[Can't Ctrl drag views to header file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483409/cant-ctrl-drag-views-to-header-file)" didn't work for me because even if the assistant is in Automatic mode I don't see my file.

I am trying to create a new IBOutlet connection, but this doesn't work. I open the xib file at the left side of my screen and I open manually the .m file from the assistant editor. I select it manually because it doesn't show up in the Automatic selection. And every time I try to connect it to my .m file it just doesn't happen.

Comment: Check the "File's Owner" in your xib.

Comment: Do you mean .h rather than .m? Because if you're trying to add it to the .m it probably won't work. EDIT: it will work, but only in a very specific sections.

Comment: Well it won't work...

Comment: Did you set Custom Class in identity inspector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it,

the problem was that I hadn't created the class that corresponds to the xib file and that's why I was having this issue. It is important to create the class with implementation(or just declare implementation) prior to creating the xib file and then you are able to add the IBOutlet connection.

That's all.